# Python - Mako templates: How to check for incoming string?

Tags: python, string, mako

I'm using Mako templates in a Python project.

The value None sometimes comes through for a contact title. I want to hide **None** if the value is `None`.

[image]

Current code:

```
<td class="data-career request-row">
    %if 'title' in message['contact'] and 'title' is not 'None':
        ${message['contact']['title']}
    %endif
</td>
```

I also tried:

```
%if 'title' in message['contact'] and 'title' is not None:
```

However None still shows up, so I'm curious as to what the correct way to check for an incoming string value is in Mako?

I couldn't find anything on their [docs site](http://www.makotemplates.org/).

Comment: Does `%if message['contact'].get('title'):` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously string `'title'` cannot be `None` because it is... well, `'title'`. :D

```
%if 'title' in message['contact'] and message['contact']['title'] is not None:
    ${message['contact']['title']}
%endif
```

or

```
%if 'title' in message['contact']:
    ${message['contact']['title'] or ''}
%endif
```

or simpliest/shortest

```
${message['contact'].get('title', None) or ''}
```

Comment: Ah thanks so much! /facepalm and cool, was wondering if I could write it without and `if else`